# First order stationarity hypothesis testing (For unknown constant mean) using R

Tags: r, time-series

The case here is that i have over 1000 time series (daily prices of products) and i try to identify if the mean of each of the above time series is constant over the time (this constant is unknown).

I believe that what i am looking for is a hypothesis test for first order stationarity but my search always returns tests for second order stationarity.

Is there a relevant test that i can use (preferably using R)? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: There are two related questions you should look at on Cross-validated [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/what-method-to-test-if-the-mean-is-constant) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164254/what-is-a-test-that-i-can-use-to-determine-if-a-time-series-is-first-order-stati)

Comment: thank youo Barker, really appreciated.